# Manually Connection between SQL Server and Model

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I created a empty project in ASP.Net and then I manually add it view,controller and model. Now I want to connect SQL Server to Model class. How can I do it ?

Comment: Does it get worse? "Help, I do not know how to program and am not willing to read some documentation" ;)

Comment: to Kevin :I just ask a question but you just tell bullshit. please be polite and just answer the questions.

Comment: No, you want someone to do it for you rather than research it yourself - that is not what SO is for. A simple Google would easily answer your question

Comment: to TomTom : If you have a brain, you must know that a person who ask question in StackOverFlow definitely read documentation. please keep your junky advise in your mouth.

Comment: to Kevin : I don't want to google it and it is none of your business that I ask this question. if you can't answer my question please don't blabber.

Comment: @user1485459: You may think that your question is just fine. But what you think is not always true. TomTom has earned 21K reputations in this site. I am sure he has a very nice brain. You better read the faq before asking your next question: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Comment: Voted down by the way, the question does not seem to be appropiate for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try with this code, this code contain select query for just example    

    // Is your string connection to your database and server
    string connectionString = ""; //connection to your database

        //Create a connection to your database
        //using bloc , in order to destruct connection object in the end of treatment
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {

            //Create object command who contain your query sql, permit you to get data or       //insert on update or delete data
            using (SqlCommand command= connection.CreateCommand())

                {
                    //for example a query, who select data from table in your databse, 
                    command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Table where col = @ParameterTest";
                    //for exxample a parameter for your query
                    command.Parameters.Add("@ParameterTest", 123); //your test value


                    //after create connection you must open this  
                    command.Connection.Open();
                    //get data in reader, structure for readin datas
                    var reader = command.ExecuteDataReader();


                }
        }
```